# Push notifications not working in production mode

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am implementing push notifications, it's working in development mode.
In production mode, when I run the application I get this message in Xcode but the application installs on the device.

> launch failed: failed to get the task for process 11288

After opening the app on device I get token id, but not get the notification, when I run `simple.php` file in terminal I get message as

```
connected to APN
Message successfully delivered
```

I have used AdHoc production provisioning certificate to test the application.

Can you tell me how to test push notifications in production.

Comment: Can you paste code of php file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a production push certificate, which you can generate the same way you do with a development certificate (just choose production), as well as change your server address from `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` to `gateway.push.apple.com`...

EDIT: You are not allowed to debug production apps, which is why you get that Xcode error in production mode...

Comment: now working problem is the token id worong in simple.php file. now i get the notification, but when i run the application, in Xcode show message as           launch failed: failed to get the task for process 11845.

Comment: Yes, you can't debug a production app... It's working fine, just Xcode isn't allowed to connect to it to see the output from the console... If you need to debug it you'll need to use a `UIAlertView` or something...

Answer (score 0):

First, You get the following error

```
launch failed: failed to get the task for process 11288
```

Because, you are running app in Production (adhoc/distribution/release) scheme mode.

Second,Your pem file and its password should be correct. Also make sure you are using the correct gateway for Production.

We could help you more, if you can share your server file here.
Thanks

Comment: now working problem is the token id worong in simple.php file. now i get the notification, but when i run the application, in Xcode show message as           launch failed: failed to get the task for process 11845.